# ios7 initWithNibName

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7

I'm making an app that determines a user's location and makes the `[locationManager startUpdatingLocation]` call in the `initWithNibName` function, but `initWithNibName` isn't being called right off the back so I added a call for it in the `AppDelegate.m`:

```
WhereamiViewController *wvc = [[WhereamiViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"WhereamiViewController" bundle:nil];
```

This works, however then there is a problem with calling this function within the `initWithNibName` function: `[locationManager startUpdatingLocation]`. It literally returns nothing. But, if I change my code to call `initWithNibName` in my `viewDidLoad` line, it works. Why is this? I'm very confused and have been searching for answers but I'm at a standstill. I understand initWithNibName needs to be called, but I don't understand why it won't work if I call it from `AppDelegate.m`.

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager
     didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations`

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager
    didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
```

Here is my initWithNibName function:

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];

    if (self) {
        locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];

        locationManager.delegate = self;
        locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyKilometer;

        // Set a movement threshold for new events.
        locationManager.distanceFilter = 500; // meters

        [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
    }

    return self;
}
```

Comment: How many different places are you calling initWithNibName (or any init flavor) on that view controller class?

Comment: just once. either in appdelegate.m or in viewdidload.

Comment: xcode is an IDE only. it is NOT an api or a sdk

Comment: You don't necessarily need to do this in initWithNibName, you could do it in viewDidLoad, but how you do it depends on how and when this view controller is instantiated and put on screen.

Comment: @rdelmar this is a single view application. I thought initWithNibName would be called automatically

Comment: Depends on how and where you made the controller. If it's made in a storyboard, initWithCoder is called instead.

Answer (score 0):

you do have a Xib file set up right?
things to try:
if you are not using Nibs then create a method called init:

```
- (id) init {
self = [super init];
if(self) {
    //call code here
}
return self;
}
```

and then instead of calling nib method in app delegate just call init

or second option would be to call the code straight in viewdidload instead of doing above

Comment: it's going into the method, like it was with initWithNibName, but `- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager
     didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations` isn't being called just like in initWithNibName